# HTML, CSS..: different font size in buttons and selects than for plain text (at least in FF)

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have this rule:

```
body {

    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px
}
```

but i have different font size for the selects and the buttons then for plain text.

What should i do if i want the same size for everything?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
body,
input,
select,
button {
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

formular elements usualy don't inherit those properties, so you have to do:

```
body{
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
input, select, button{
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

Comment: +1, do you know if inherit works also for TD elements to inherit parent font-size/font-family?

Comment: This should be the preferred answer. Great stuff.

Answer (score 3):

By default, form elements like input of type text and password (submit and button ?), select, textarea and button are styled with a monospace font with a resulting size of approx. 13.33px.
You can check `C:\Program Files\Firefox\res\forms.css` (under WinXP) or with Firebug in the HTML part, the little triangle at the right of Style tab ==> Default CSS properties

```
body {
  font: normal 62.5%/1.5 Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

input, select, textarea, button {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

will result in `12px`+`Verdana` form elements (and `1em = 10px` equivalence for your whole page)

Comment: Hi, could you explain where does that come from ? (the default font-size)

Comment: @PaulCo It's the default UA CSS (the styles applied by each browser to an HTML page before any other user and author/developer ones). Can now be found [here for Firefox](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/layout/style/res/forms.css). I don't know what `font: -moz-field;` means but that's what is applied :) You can see those default styles in modern DevTools by activating an option

Comment: Thanks for this info ! I'm still surprised that you cannot see this on MDN or other platform.

Comment: Forgot to mention my source for the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3980775/137626 (remove html.css in the Fx link to see all the files but, well, it's simpler in F12 on a per element basis). There's also a link to WebKit (both are open source, it helps!). Moreover, W3C HTML 5 has [suggestions](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#rendering). And finally, normalize.css and reboot.css will help you not having to consider those differences (reset CSS are another beast: they'll kill any style which is too much imho)

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button {
  font:inherit
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>An example of a sans-serif font</p>
  <button>Cick Me</button>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Could you please extend your answer with some details about why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about buttons, but most browsers try to style `<select>` elements in a standard way (e.g. 12-point Arial). If you want to change the style of these, you have to add an explicit CSS rule:

```
select {    
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```