# HTML tags default styles question?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Browser’s Default CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875/browsers-default-css)

Is there a list of the default html elements styles that I can look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS specification [suggests one](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html), but every browser is different (which is why people use reset stylesheets).

Answer (score 0):

Every browser uses different default styles.

You may want to check reset-css which sets the styles to a defined default.
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to understand how browsers render elements by default is create your own demo page.  Just make a HTML page with a bunch of HTML elements, and view it in a browser.  Even better, submit it to [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) and see it in a whole bunch of browsers at once.

Not sure where you can get a comprehensive list of styles for each browser, however.