# Where can I get a list of the default css settings for elements?

Tags: css

For example

```
body { margin:0;  }
```

renders differently than no .css for the body element.

Comment: It depends on the browser. The best way to be sure about these settings is by zeroing them out yourself with a reset.css See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset

Comment: browsers render them differently, that's why a "CSS reset" exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875/browsers-default-css - the top answer really sucks though

Comment: @BoltClock You recommend a *normalizer* rather than a *reset*?

Comment: @alex: I like normalize.css but that's not relevant. I'm referring to the fact that the top answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh yes, but still helpful.

Comment: @BoltClock: [ಠ_ಠ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript/311071#311071) (I'm sorry, I couldn't resist. But seriously, please kill it with fire. Question: How do I set CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript? Answer: Here's a link to some irrelevant documentation saying it can't be done.)

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) uses a great "normalizing"-css. Give it a try.