# Empty span has height in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm a little surprised of strange behaviour of Firefox
empty span has height:

```
var height,
    width,
    infoText = "",
    $span = $('<span></span>');

$('body').append($span);
$span.text(infoText);
height = $span.height();
width = $span.width();
$('body').append(' height: ' + height);
$('body').append(' width: ' + width);
```

[jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/wV8H6/1/)

reproduced only in Firefox (FF version is 27.0)
in Opera, Chrome and IE height = 0

is it FF bug?

Comment: to understand this, i think you need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875/browsers-default-css-stylesheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add following code in span..

```
var height,
    width,
    infoText = "",
    $span = $('<span style="display:inline-block;"></span>');
```

now height should be 0px.

Answer (score 0):

By default `span's display is inline` so add `display:inline-block` in your `span` or add this in **CSS** like,

```
span{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wV8H6/2/)