# bootstrap 3.2.0 nested input in label width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">
        Last name
        <input style="font-weight: normal;" required maxlength="50" type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName">
    </label>
</div>
```

The input width is 210px in Firefox, 177px in Chrome, but I can't find the constant in the css after inspecting the element. The label "Last name" is much thinner than 210px. If I change the label to a very long string, the input's width will adjust accordingly(100%). However, I'm looking for where the minimum width is defined. I am using this markup so that I don't need to give the label a for attribute equal to the id of its input. I could easily explicitly set the width, but I'm just curious where this value came from. If these are browser styles, then how can I view them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `input.form-control` is set to `100%` which means 100% of whatever it's parent is.  In this case, that's the label control.

The difference in the default label width is likely due to differences in each [browser's default stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32875/1366033)

If you'd like the input to take up the full width, but don't want to type out a long label, you can just set:

```css
.form-group > label { width: 100%; }
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/3e3GP/)