# Removing the skipped line above an unordered list

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the skipped line that always occurs above an html list?  For example, in the code below, I have a line of text that describes the list, followed by the list itself.  There is an unsightly blank line after the description and before the first item on the list.  **How can I change the code below so that the first list item is immediately below the description?**

*Description of list:*

- First item.
- Second item.
- Third item.

Here is the code that needs to be changed:

```
<i>Description of list:</i>
<ul>
    <li>First item.</li>
    <li>Second item.</li>
    <li>Third item.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `margin` property?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618000/why-ul-adds-extra-top-margin has your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if i am understand this correctly but check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLj4wgzL/)

The browser puts in default margin on the top and bottom of a UL so you could remove the margin using...

```
ul{margin-top: 0;}
```

Comment: You were the first one with the correct answer.  Thank you and +1.  The stack overflow gods won't let me accept an answer for another 5 minutes.

Comment: LOL the stackoverflow gods hate that rule, But Glad it is working for ya, Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

It's the default `margin` at the top of the list. You can remove -- or reduce -- it with CSS.

```css
ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<i>Description of list:</i>
<ul>
  <li>First item.</li>
  <li>Second item.</li>
  <li>Third item.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

> provide an id to the element 'ul' and then move up the elements using
>   margin-top

DEMO :http://jsfiddle.net/oc8mdc2s/2/

```
<i >Description of list:</i>
<ul id="listing">
    <li>First item.</li>
    <li>Second item.</li>
    <li>Third item.</li>
</ul>



#listing{
    margin-top:-0.01%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to add a different insight.  But I tried your code and it does not work in the unique setting in which the code is run.  I am inserting the html into a web site not unlike stack overflow (but run by a different company).  Most of my other html formatting works in that environment, but the blank line above each list is retained no matter what formatting I have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

to remove space between description and List item you will need to reset Un ordered List item properties

**CSS**

```
ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

above code will reset default browser properties which are getting applied to Un ordered list item.

Comment: _“applied to Un ordered list item”_: not to the _items_, but to the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider reading about reseting css styles and default values for each tag. In your example you can try do it with

```
ul {margin:0;}
```

or just reseting one of margins.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't have existing CSS files when modifying some internal documentation, so I struggled to implement the other answers.  A quick html-only fix is to put the following:

```
<style>ul{margin-top:0;}</style>
```

somewhere just inside the head element:

```
<head>
:
</head>
```

at the top of the html file.