# HTML white space

Tags: html, css

i am new to css & html and i have this problem where when i make a website 
there is some white space on top even if padding = 0 
take a look on my html

```css
header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #0e83cd;
}
nav ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Num1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Num2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
```

**EDIT**
dwreck08, Aziz Solved my problem
by adding padding 0 and margin 0 to html , body
THANKS

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find it. tl;dr - `<ul>` has inherent `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of `16px`. Remove that manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why <ul> adds extra top margin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618000/why-ul-adds-extra-top-margin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply:

`html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0;}` and `nav ul {margin: 0;}`

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgr8kkn8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the default browser styling, try this:

```
html, body {padding:0; margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must reset the browser native `css`:
try to link this stylesheet.

Link: https://rawgit.com/jasonkarns/css-reset/master/reset.css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tgr8kkn8/2/