# display: inline-block adds vertical padding

Tags: html, css, padding

I have the following HTML and CSS:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  background-color: red;
  /* display: inline-block; */
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>one</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and when I use `inline-block` in my CSS it looks like this:

[image]

but without `display:inline-block` it looks like this (which is perfectly okay, presuming display is `block` by default):

[image]

So where does this vertical padding come from?

Comment: This question is already answered in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618000/why-ul-adds-extra-top-margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The padding comes from your unordered list and collapsing margins. When you don't have display: inline-block on the parent (div.row), that div displays as a block element by default and the [margins collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Margin_collapsing). You can see this by applying the standard remedy for collapsing margins by adding `overflow: auto` to the div.row element.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  background-color: red;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  overflow:auto;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>one</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The easiest way to get rid of that extra space is to set the margin to zero on the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

The margin comes from `ul`'s default margin, whenever I've removed the margin from the `ul`, it aligned like you wanted.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>one</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```