# Why is there space between the document and my navigator?

Tags: css

The padding and margin of the body and my navigator has been set to 0, yet there is still space between the top part of my navigator. How do I fix this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header_container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 119);
}
```

```html
<div id="header_container">
  <ul>
    <li id="homepage_name">name</li>
    <div id="buttons">
      <li id="home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li id="about_us">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li id="contacts">Contacts</li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! @Gab could you please upload a screenshot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why <ul> adds extra top margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618000/why-ul-adds-extra-top-margin)

Answer (score 1):

Also need to remove margin from ul.

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#header_container {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 119);
}
ul{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_container">
    <ul>
        <li id="homepage_name">name</li>
        <div id="buttons">
            <li id="home">Home</a></li>
            <li id="about_us">About us</a></li>
            <li id="contacts">Contacts</li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```