# CSS Property Inheritance and HTML Elements

Tags: html, css

I understand how CSS inheritance works, but I'm having trouble finding a good resource that indicates what properties the CSS spec initially applies to standard HTML elements like `div`, `span`, and `ul`. A `div` element is a block element, and a `span` element will be placed `inline`. These elements naturally have properties that cause these different behaviors, they aren't inherited. For example, if a `span` element and a `div` are two sibling elements that are direct descendants of the `html` element, they would still differ in behavior.

Where can I find a list of the CSS properties that each element initially has?

Comment: are you looking for [browser default styleshets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875/browsers-default-css-stylesheets)?

Comment: You seem to be asking two different but linked questions here: 1) how inheritance works for properties where inheritance doesn't make sense, and 2) what default styles are applied to various elements. The answer to #1 is that CSS defines which properties are inherited by default and which are not - display is one of those properties that are not inherited by default because, as you've correctly pointed out, it doesn't make sense for that property to be inherited.

Comment: For example, you have to specify 'border-box' over 'content-box' for a div element, where is this specified? The browser default stylesheet for 'div' only has `display: block;`.

Comment: There is [this W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html) which lists "Typical default display properties" for each of the elements. Does that help?

Comment: If you want the default stylesheet values for the browsers, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875/browsers-default-css-stylesheets (which does have some links you might be interested in).

Comment: Hmm, I was more interested in what the "typical default display properties" are. Is there not an exhaustive list of the properties that they have? `box-sizing: border-box` appears in neither of these lists for `div`, how would one know that there are changeable properties of the `div` element?

Answer (score 1):

> For example, you have to specify 'border-box' over 'content-box' for a div element, where is this specified? The browser default stylesheet for 'div' only has `display: block;`.

Properties that do not appear for a given element in a browser's default stylesheet are assumed to be what is known as their *initial value* for that element. This initial value is defined not by the browser, but by CSS (although of course a browser implementation can violate the spec as it so wishes).

As I mentioned in my comment, some properties, such as `color`, are designed to be inherited by default, while others, such as `display` and `box-sizing`, are not inherited by default because inheritance simply doesn't make sense for those properties.

You can find both the initial value and the inheritance information for a given property in either the propdef in the respective [W3C CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work), or, if you prefer a more author-friendly reference, in one of many third-party resources such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) or [WebPlatform.org](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css).

For example, the initial value of `box-sizing` is `content-box`, and it is not inherited by default. This property is defined in the [CSS User Interface module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui-3/#box-sizing). This is why you need to explicitly declare `box-sizing: border-box` if you want to use that value.

Comment: That last link you posted is helpful. It is evident that `div` has an initial value of `content-box` because the document specified "Applies to: all elements that accept width or height", but it would be nice to be able to search for an element, like a `div` or a `span` and determine which properties are applied to it. I guess this functionality isn't available?

Comment: @Himmel: The thing about CSS is that, with a few exceptions, virtually *any* CSS property can be applied to *any* HTML element regardless of browser defaults. So when it says "Applies to: all elements that accept width or height", it really means all elements that are not display: none/inline/table-row/table-row-group. As such I don't think there are tools available to determine this sort of information - all I have at my disposal is my knowledge of the internal workings of CSS.

Comment: It just seems strange that you have to take a deductive approach to determine these initial property values (height/width -> div) rather than there being a source that allows you to see ALL of the properties and initial values that an HTML element contains.

Comment: @Himmel: I agree. You *could* create a dummy element in a blank page and inspect its styles, but browsers tend to list used values rather than computed values, although they do try to point out if a certain property was taken from the default stylesheet.