# CSS stick footer background to bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
.footer {
 background-image: url("./images/footer.png");
 height: 45px;
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 0;
 }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>My title</title>
 </head>
<body>
  .. some header divs..
  .. some content divs..
 <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Footer is about 10 pixels before bootom. How I can add it to the very bottom of the page?

Comment: I'm not sure your going to find a complete solution with your example above... What if the user has a 5K monitor and your content only fills half of the screen. You should look at adding the footers background to the body class and then setting content elements background color independently to cover all possible scenarios.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browsers' default CSS stylesheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875/browsers-default-css-stylesheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```