# How can I make elements take width of html element?

Tags: html, css

For whatever reason, I can't seem to put the right words in my search engine. It seems like a really easy thing. Let's say I have simple markup as follows:

```
<div>Hello!</div>
```

And I apply the following styles:

```
body {
  background: blue;
}

div {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Now ideally, I'd like the green to stretch across the entire screen, but for whatever reason theres a buffer between the ends of the window and the div, that are blue. When I go to inspect the div, I note that there is 0 padding/margin and just the content box. When I inspect the HTML element. it's just the content with no padding/margin as well.

I guess my question is, how can I get rid of that blue buffer area between the html and the containing div? The only way I have successfully done it, is negative margins on the div, but that seems hacky. Any thoughts?

Comment: Keep in mind that divs are display:block by default and they already fill the width of the container. The margin on the body is the part you're missing, see the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even without any CSS applied, every browser does some [default styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875/browsers-default-css-stylesheets) of elements. This includes margin on the `body` element. To overwrite these default styles (which you can inspect via your browser's developer tools, if any - for example via <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome), you just set custom CSS rules accordingly. For your specific problem, you should add `margin: 0` to the styling of the `body` tag.

Now, since every browser has different defaults, many developers decide to *reset* the styling entirely before applying their own. This can make for a more consistent and streamlined CSS developing process. There are several of these reset stylings available, a famous one being [Eric Meyer's CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/).

Comment: ugh, yeah, i feel dumb, i thought I had tried the margin 0 on body, ofc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Body element has default margin at every direction 8px long, so just rewrite this default.

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   background: blue;
}
```

@Edit:
...also It's great example to practice 'Developer Tools' using. There's nice guide: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Answer (score 0):

You should consult the [CSS box model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) when you have questions like this one.  You just need to remove the margin from the body.

```css
body {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0px
}

div {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello!</div>
```