# h1 creates unwanted space above the text

Tags: css, html

I'm sure my question is quite a newbie one, anyway I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Basically, I created a `<div>` that I use as header, and inside of it another `<div>` that contains an image (logo) and a title (using `<h1>`).

The problem is that I get an unwanted extra space above the body
[as you can see in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmpgI.png)
If I get rid of the `<h1>` title then everything is fine. I think the problem is due the `float: left;` property that I have assigned to the image, because if I assign no float property then the space disappears, but [as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGsLg.png) if I remove the `float: left;` the image and the title are not "aligned" anymore. So, the question is, how can I make the image to stay on the left and the title on the right of the image, without using float properties?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Edit: Thanks everybody for the answers, I'm studying HTML and CSS at school and things like this are rarely mentioned by my teachers. Thanks again

Comment: That's called Collapsing Margins, https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 1):

A h1 element has margin by default. Simply remove it by adding:

```
margin: 0;
```

To the styles for your h1 element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
<h1 style="margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px">some text</h1>
```

Comment: Padding wouldn't push the page elements just increase the space around the text in the h1 element

Answer (score 0):

At start of your work you should clear the style for margin (browser apply some of them).
So just in start of css file write:

```
h1 { 
  margin: 0;
}
```

A lot of devs just start a css file like :

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

for clear it :)
Also you should read something about css reset and css normalize :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because every browser has a default stylesheet, which you can find in [Browsers' default CSS stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875/browsers-default-css-stylesheets). As you can see, the default margins are not zero. This can be solved by explicitly adding `margin: 0px` to your CSS.